# How to remove whitespace after abbreviations

Tags: acronyms, white-space

How can I remove unwanted white-space present when using macros from the `abbrevs` package?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{abbrevs}
\begin{document}
Socretes (470-399\BC) annoyed Aristophanes. % gives (470-399 B.C. ) not (470-399 B.C.)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `abbrevs` is an 'aged' package and seems a little bit peculiar. Have you checked the `\nospacelist` macro in order to get rid of the space? I also suggest to switch to `glossaries` or `acro` or `acronym` packages rather

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The strange thing is, this also happens if `)` is in the `\nospacelist`.

Comment: @samcarter: I did not check. Seems to be a bug then

Comment: Even more important than getting rid of the unwanted space: Fixing the spelling of poor old Socrates... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{abbrevs}
\begin{document}
Socretes (470-399\BC.) annoyed Aristophanes. % gives (470-399 B.C. ) not (470-399 B.C.)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Socrates or Socretes?

Comment: @Mico This is probably the evil twin brother.